# Library function to compose a function with itself n times

Tags: haskell

Is there a library function available in Haskell to compose a function with itself *n* times?

For example I have this function:

```
func :: a -> a
```

and I want to do this:

```
func . func . func . func . func . func , ...
```

(up to *n* times, where *n* is only known at runtime).

Note that the iterate function would not be appropriate for what I am doing, since I do not care about any intermediate results.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The `iterate` solution is fine, or you might like this one: the composition of `n` copies of `f` is `foldr (.) id (replicate n f)`.

Comment: @John  The other solutions (`iterate` with `!!` or `lookup . zip`) also work with n == 0.  Look at the [definition of iterate](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.1/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.0/src/GHC-List.html#iterate) and you'll see it starts the list with the base case.

Comment: @TomMD you're right, my mistake.  I was thinking of a different definition using `iterate`, which isn't nearly as nice as what you provided.

Comment: When I use this with `map` as `f` in GHCI, I get an infinite type error.

Comment: It appears to be a problem involving return type polymorphic recursion.

Answer (score 29):

```
\xs n -> iterate func xs !! n
```

(`xs` is the initial value, `n` is the number of times to apply `func`)

I don't know why, but I feel like `iterate` is something people aren't consistently exposed to when learning Haskell.

If you don't like `!!` then you could use `zip` and `lookup` as an alternative.  (some people/groups/tools don't like functions that call "error" in certain cases, I'm not claiming lookup is any better in these cases)

```
lookup n . zip [0..] . iterate func
```

EDIT: Ok, so I deleted then undeleted because I agree with the other answerer - you shouldn't discount use of iterate just because it gives you *more* than you need.

Comment: For what it's worth, since `iterate` guarantees an infinite list, I would use `(!!)` or `genericIndex` over using `lookup` with `zip`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was getting out about `lookup` and `zip` not being any better in these cases.  `(!!)` has a stigma much like `head` does (or, that's my impression)

Comment: Yes, it's a well-deserved stigma in my opinion too, but all it really means is that you have to be careful about using it in cases where it might not apply - not that you should never use it.  As trinithis points out, in this case it cannot go wrong except when passed a negative index.  Incidentally !! is actually a demonstrably better choice than lookup here:  lookup and zip will loop forever on a negative index, looking for a result that isn't there, but !! will fail immediately because it knows indices can't be negative.

Answer (score 14):

I do not know why you say that `iterate` is not appropriate.  It is perfectly suitable for this purpose.  `(!! n) . iterate func` is the composition of `n` copies of `func`.

(Someone had posted an answer similar to the above code, but he/she seems to have deleted it.)

Answer (score 12):

`(\n -> appEndo . mconcat . replicate n . Endo) n f x`

Answer (score 8):

I'm a beginner in Haskell, currently on chapter 5 ("Higher Order Functions") of [Learn You a Haskell For Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) so I'm not yet familiar with the functions shown in the previous replies. Given what I understand so far, I'd do it like this:

```
applyNTimes :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
applyNTimes n f x 
    | n == 0        = x
    | otherwise     = f (applyNTimes (n-1) f x)
```

Comment: The only thing I would do differently is pattern matching instead of using guards: `applyNTimes 0 _ x = x` and then `applyNTimes n f x = f $ applyNTimes (n-1) f x`. Actually, you should be able to remove all the x's from that as well.

Comment: This is also a good solution, it should remind the reader of an explicit proof by induction on [n].

Comment: Notice that this is strictly better than `| otherwise = applyNTimes (n-1) f (f x)`, because `f` might be lazy.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version that has complexity O(log n) instead of O(n) (to build the function, not to apply it):

```
composeN 0 f = id
composeN n f
    | even n = g
    | odd  n = f . g
    where g = g' . g'
          g' = composeN (n `div` 2) f
```

Comment: How has this got so few votes. Is there something wrong with it?

Comment: @matt Probably because I was late to the party, and because the time complexity of building the function isn't really relevant when you still need O(N) time to execute it anyway.

Answer (score 4):

```
\n -> appEndo . foldMap Endo . replicate n
```

Answer (score 2):

A variation on [trinithis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911060/library-function-to-compose-a-function-with-itself-n-times/3911614#3911614) using the [newtype](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype) package, just for fun:

```
(\n f -> under Endo (mconcat . replicate n) f)
```

Or point-free:

```
under Endo . (mconcat .) . replicate
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using `foldr`:

`\n -> flip (foldr ($)) . replicate n`

Comment: Would `(\n -> flip (Data.List.foldl' (flip ($))) . replicate n) 5 (+1) 1` be a tad bit stricter?

Answer (score 0):

```
iterate (f .) id !! n
```

or

```
iterate (f .) f !! (n-1)
```

depending on if `n == 0` is allowed.