# How to call the same function 'n' times?

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Library function to compose a function with itself n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911060/library-function-to-compose-a-function-with-itself-n-times)

I need a function to call another function n number of times.

so it would look something like this
f n = g(g(g(g(l))))
where n equals to the number of function g nested.

how should I go about this? thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3911060/465466

Comment: This really is a repeat of the question Tsuyoshi linked to. Should this one be closed then?

Comment: Davorak: But this way I get double the points for the same answer.  Seriously though, I forgot about that previous question.  Perhaps SO should have a better filter process for repeat questions - we've been getting a lot of those lately and they really don't add any value.

Answer (score 84):

[`iterate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:iterate) is a common solution:

```
> :t iterate
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
```

So, given a function with a domain the same as its range, `a -> a`, and an initial input `a`, produce an infinite list of results in the form:

```
iterate f a --> [a, f(a), f(f(a)), ...]
```

And you can access the nth element of the list using [`!!`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-):

```
iterate f a !! n
```

NB `iterate f a !! 0 == a`.

Comment: `take n $ iterate f a` also works

Comment: @abhillman, no it doesn't. Your expression returns a *list* of `n` compositions of `f`, not the `n`th composition.

Answer (score 11):

This is a function that I use often at the ghci prompt.  There are a few ways to write it, none of which I am particularly fond of, but they are all reasonably clean:

```
fpow n f x = iterate f x !! n

fpow n f = foldr (.) id $ replicate n f

fpow n = foldr (.) id . replicate n   -- just eta the above

fpow 0 f = id
fpow n f = f . fpow (n-1) f
```

The middle two appeal to me because my brain has chunked `foldr (.) id` to mean "compose a list of functions".

I kinda just wish it were in the prelude :-).

Comment: I randomly thought of [`compose2`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821089/haskell-function-composition-operator-of-type-cd-abc-abd/5822800#5822800), or `(.*) = (.) . (.)`, which allows you to write it pointlessly: `fpow = foldr (.) id .* replicate`

Answer (score 7):

```
f 0 = l
f n = g (f (n-1))
```

But more functional would be:

```
f 0 l = l
f n l = g (f (n-1) l)
```

This could also be done with folds or morfisms, but this is easier to understand.

For example here's using a hylomorphism, but it doesn't make it clearer really:

```
f g l = hylo l (.) (\n -> (g, n-1)) (==0)
```

It says some thing like compose (.) g(l) until n==0

Answer (score 4):

Can be done using fold:

```
applyNTimes :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
applyNTimes n f val = foldl (\s e -> e s) val [f | x <- [1..n]]
```