# Haskell simple beginner sorting program

Tags: sorting, haskell

Still pretty new to Haskell. I'm trying to write a sort function using recursion, and this is what I have so far:

```
sort' :: [Int] -> [Int]
sort' [] = []
sort' [x] = [x]
sort' (x:y:xs) = 
  if x > y
    then y:sort' (x:xs)
    else x:sort' (y:xs)
```

From what I can tell it works fine when there are fewer than 2 elements to be sorted. But if I enter [3,2,1], I get [2,1,3]. I've tried following the path of the inputs manually, but I can't figure out how to sort more than the 2 initial elements. I've done a bit of reading, and was thinking about something involving `iterate` and use the length of the list (`length`), but I'm not sure how to implement it if it does work.

Comment: Your `sort'` is doing a single iteration of a bubblesort. You can indeed iterate your function multiple times to get a fully sorted list. Here's how that looks when done manually: `sort' (sort' (sort' (sort' (sort' [4,2,1,3,5]))))`, and it does result in `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: I tried reading the documentation on `iterate` but it didn't really make much sense. How could I use it in this context, using the length of the input list as the number of times to reapply `sort'`?

Comment: `iterate f x = [x, f x, f (f x), ...]`, so `iterate f x !! n` is `f` applied `n` times to `x`. So if you want to apply `sort' (sort' (sort' ... xs))` with `(length xs)` `sort'`s, you should be able to just write `sort xs = iterate sort' xs !! length xs`

Comment: Another option, which might be a bit slower, but very clear would be something like `until isSorted sort' xs`, with an appropriate definition of `isSorted`. You might also be interested in some other sorting algorithms in Haskell; both top-down and (especially) bottom-up mergesorts are very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `sort'` implements an iteration of bubble sort, and it follows that applying it over and over will result in a completely sorted list. There are [many ways of doing that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423123/how-to-call-the-same-function-n-times), with one being to use `iterate` to repeatedly apply it, and picking the N'th application using `!!`:

```
completeSort list = iterate sort' list !! length list
```

Answer (score 0):

As @that other guy points out, you can use `iterate` to apply `sort'` to a list `n` times, which is a wonderful example of using higher-level combinators in Haskell (as opposed to primitive recursion). Another nice combinator that is useful for this sort of thing is `until`: `until` will take a predicate `:: a -> Bool`, a function `:: a -> a`, and a value `:: a`, and will apply the function to the value until the predicate remains true. So when you have a similar situation but don't know exactly how many passes you want to make over the input, you can do something like `until isSorted sort' xs`, which can be quite nice.

A lot of other one-pass sorting algorithms are quite nice in Haskell as well, including top-down and (especially) bottom-up mergesorts.

At the risk of throwing you into the theory deep end, I wanted to mention another quite nice high-level combinatorial way of thinking about iterating `n` times.  This is based on the idea of "recursion schemes", where the basic idea is that the structure of a recursive datatype informs useful patterns for processing/transforming it. As it happens, Haskell is powerful enough to express a lot of these ideas. One of the simplest examples of the recursion scheme is based on the natural numbers:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
```

This is a recursive datatype because the second data constructor refers back to `Nat` itself. There's a really natural way of processing `Nat`s, which is to say: when I have `Zero`, I should return some value; otherwise I should recursively process the `Nat` and then use those values to come up with a new value.  As it happens, we can write `Nat` in a different way, which makes this very easy to do generally:

```
data NatF a = Zero | Succ a
type Nat = Mu NatF
```

Now, the `NatF` data type can hold a value of any type inside its "recursive" component, instead of only another `Nat`.  The `Mu` type constructor in the second line is basically like the `fix` function but for types: it instantiates `NatF (NatF (NatF (NatF ...)))` so that `Nat = NatF Nat`, which is the same as our earlier definition.

Because of the increased genericity, though, we can now write down the a type that describes functions that process `Nat`s as described above: `NatF a -> a`. When given a `Zero`, a function of this type just returns some `a`; when given a `Succ`, it has access to the `a` that it returned when it was recursively called on the "inside" `Nat`.  It turns out that it's possible to generalize the infrastructure needed to do this, so that it can work on any type written in the style above (i.e. as a fixed point of a type generalized over the recursive component). This means that you can just write down the equations for your function given the results from recursive calls and then call `cata` on this datastructure, without ever having to be bothered to write down the repetitive boring recursive calls!

It also means that another way to write your "apply sort' (length xs) times to  xs` is:

```
sort xs = cata phi (toNat $ length xs)
  where phi Zero = xs
        phi (Succ xs) = sort' xs
```