# Haskell: repeat a function a large number of times without stackoverflow

Tags: haskell, stack-overflow

As a newbie to Haskell I am trying to iterate a function (e.g., the logistic map) a large number of times. In an imperative language this would be a simple loop, however in Haskell I end up with stack overflow. Take for example this code:

```
main  = print $ iter 1000000

f x = 4.0*x*(1.0-x)

iter :: Int -> Double
iter 0 = 0.3
iter n = f $ iter (n-1)
```

For a small number of iterations the code works, but for a million iterations I get a stack space overflow:

```
Stack space overflow: current size 8388608 bytes.
Use `+RTS -Ksize -RTS' to increase it.
```

I cannot understand why this does happen. The tail recursion should be fine here.
Maybe the problem is lazy evaluation. I experimented with several ways to force strict evaluation, by inserting `$!` or `seq` at various positions, but with no success.

What would be the Haskell way to iterate a function a huge number of times?

I have tried suggestions from related posts: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911060) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423123/), but I always ended up with stackoverflow for a large number of iterations, e.g., `main = print $ iterate f 0.3 !! 1000000`.

Comment: the problem is that you don't have a tail recursion since you are not returning directly `iter (n-1)`

Comment: It is funny that people just don't get what tail recursion is. FYI, this definition is wrong: "when the name of the function we're just in appears on the last line of that function".

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that your definition

```
iter :: Int -> Double
iter 0 = 0.3
iter n = f $ iter (n-1)
```

tries to evaluate in the wrong direction. Unfolding it for a few steps, we obtain

```
iter n = f (iter (n-1))
       = f (f (iter (n-2)))
       = f (f (f (iter (n-3))))
       ...
```

and the entire call stack from `iter 1000000` to `iter 0` has to be built before anything can be evaluated. It would be the same in a strict language. You have to organise it so that part of the evaluation can take place before recurring. The usual way is to have an accumulation parameter, like

```
iter n = go n 0.3
  where
    go 0 x = x
    go k x = go (k-1) (f x)
```

Then adding strictness annotations - in case the compiler doesn't already add them - will make it run smoothly without consuming stack.

The `iterate` variant has the same problem as your `iter`, only the call stack is built inside-out rather than outside-in as for yours. But since `iterate` builds its call-stack inside-out, a stricter version of `iterate` (or a consumption pattern where earlier iterations are forced before) solves the problem,

```
iterate' :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate' f x = x `seq` (x : iterate' f (f x))
```

calculates `iterate' f 0.3 !! 1000000` without problem.

Comment: In other words, the original definition of `iter` isn't tail-recursive.

Comment: which makes this a great time to learn about folds! `iter n = foldl' (\acc f -> f acc) 0.3 (replicate n f)`

Comment: @JohnL Right, but tail recursion isn't _the_ important thing in Haskell, on the one hand, due to laziness/nonstrictness, tail recursive functions can still cause stack overflows by building large thunks, so one has to ensure the right amount of strictness/eagerness too. On the other hand, non-tail-recursion has no stack overflow problems if the recursive call is in the right place, e.g. a lazy constructor field (guarded recursion is the important concept here).

Comment: The last line should be `iterate' f 0.3 !! 1000000`

Comment: @rampion Why not `iter n = foldl' (\acc _ -> f acc) 0.3 [1..n]`?

Comment: @VictorMoroz: why not `iter n = foldl' (flip ($)) 0.3 . take n $ repeat f` :)  There's a bunch of ways to do it.

Comment: @DanielFischer: we're definitely in agreement about tail recursion's place in Haskell; I was just pointing out that the question followed from a mistaken premise.  If the function were tail-recursive, ghc's strictness analyzer would at least have a chance of creating good code.

Comment: @ Daniel: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what I was looking for. I understand now the logical flaw in my code and learned a lot about recursion in Haskell.