# Haskell Polymorphic Recursion with Composed Maps causes Infinite Type Error

Tags: haskell, recursion, types, polymorphism, composition

What is the right way to create a function that can dynamically create composed map?

This results in an error (also happens with fmap):

```
createComposedMaps list = accumulate list map
    where 
        accumulate (x:xs) m = accumulate xs (m.map)
        accumulate []     m = m
```

The `list` is irrelevant, it's just there to count the number of compositions.

The error I get back is about "cannot construct infinite type":

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a2 ~ [a2]
Expected type: (a2 -> b1) -> a2 -> b1
  Actual type: (a2 -> b1) -> [a2] -> [b1]
Relevant bindings include
  m :: (a2 -> b1) -> c (bound at dimensional_filter.hs:166:27)
  accumulate :: [t1] -> ((a2 -> b1) -> c) -> (a2 -> b1) -> c
    (bound at dimensional_filter.hs:166:9)
In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘map’
In the second argument of ‘accumulate’, namely ‘(m . map)’

Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: b1 ~ [b1]
Expected type: (a2 -> b1) -> a2 -> b1
  Actual type: (a2 -> b1) -> [a2] -> [b1]
Relevant bindings include
  m :: (a2 -> b1) -> c (bound at dimensional_filter.hs:166:27)
  accumulate :: [t1] -> ((a2 -> b1) -> c) -> (a2 -> b1) -> c
    (bound at dimensional_filter.hs:166:9)
In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘map’
In the second argument of ‘accumulate’, namely ‘(m . map)’
```

The goal is to create a dynamically composed mapping function that I can later use. While other semigroups can be appended together (lists, numbers...). Functions seems to be much harder.

Would appreciate an example showing fmap and/or map.

I found this [Library function to compose a function with itself n times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911060/library-function-to-compose-a-function-with-itself-n-times)

But I need to use each intermediate composition, not just the final composition. And some examples still gives me infinite type error.

Turns out the problem may involve polymorphic recursion. As each recursive application of the `accumulate` function changes the map type.

Comment: Which type do you want `createComposedMaps` to have?

Comment: I'm not sure what the type is. It takes a list and gives back some type that can be inhabited by a composed map function.

Comment: Okay. What should be the type of a composed map function? (I am not trying to annoy you, it's just that figuring out the types you want tends to clarify a lot problems of this kind.)

Comment: Well I don't know? Do you?

Comment: Not yet, as there are a few things I'm not sure of. What are you using `map` for? (I have a slight suspicion you don't actually need it.)

Comment: Look at the link here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911060/library-function-to-compose-a-function-with-itself-n-times The top answer appears to work for simple functions like `+1` but `map` doesn't work, it still results in an infinite type error. This function that I propose could be done in an untyped language with first class lambdas. I would like to know why it cannot be done in Haskell.

Comment: AFAIK you are using polymorphic recursion there so you **must** provide an explicit type signature...

Comment: @Bakuriu that lots relevant to this problem. But I don't know what the type signature for a recursive map would look like.

Comment: @CMCDragonkai I see. The key issue is that in a chain of composed `map` the type of the result changes depending on how many `map` there are. That is why we are having trouble to give `createComposedMaps` a type. If you were dealing only with `a -> a` functions you would be able to work with them as a monoid, as you suggest, and [there is even a standard type for that](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo). In your case, a workaround will be tricky, if it is even possible. Cf. [this polyvariadic function demo](http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/vararg-fn.lhs).

Comment: Perhaps something using return type polymorphism will be required, which means typeclasses...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic job for dependent types, which means that we compute return types from the values of arguments. Here we'd like to express that the nesting of the resulting list depends on a numeric input (in your case, you used the length of a list parameter as the numeric input, but it's probably better to just use numbers where numbers are needed).

Unfortunately Haskell doesn't yet have proper support for dependent typing, and existing workaround solutions involve some boilerplate and complications. [Idris](http://www.idris-lang.org/) is a language with Haskell-like syntax and full dependent types, so I can illustrate the idea in Idris with greater clarity:

```
-- unary naturals from the Idris Prelude :
-- data Nat = Z | S Nat

-- compose a function n times (which can also be a type constructor!)
-- for example, iterN 3 List Int = List (List (List Int))
iterN : Nat -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
iterN Z     f a = a
iterN (S k) f a = f (iterN k f a)

mapN : (n : Nat) -> (a -> b) -> iterN n List a -> iterN n List b
mapN Z     f as = f as
mapN (S k) f as = map (mapN k f) as

-- usage:
> mapN 3 (+10) [[[0]]]
[[[10]]]
> mapN 0 id 10
10
```

This is the complete Idris solution. In Haskell, we can't have values or functions in types, and the only way to make the above work is to create type-level versions of functions as type families and value-level versions of types as singletons, effectively writing twice as many definitions as would be ideal. The [`singletons`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) library seeks to remove the bulk of the boilerplate through Template Haskell and clever machinery. Here's a singletons-based solution:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, TypeFamilies #-}

import Data.Singletons -- package: singletons
import Data.Nat        -- package: singleton-nats (by me)

type family IterN n f a where
  IterN Z     f a = a
  IterN (S n) f a = f (IterN n f a)

mapN :: Sing n -> (a -> b) -> IterN n [] a -> IterN n [] b  
mapN SZ     f a  = f a
mapN (SS n) f as = map (mapN n f) as

-- usage:
> mapN (sing :: SLit 3) (+10) [[[0]]]
[[[10]]]
```

The good news though is that there's ongoing research and development to add dependent types to GHC and we can expect improvements in the next few years.

---

Alternatively, one might be tempted to use type classes to infer the amount of nestedness in the return type. This is fairly horrible, because we have to distinguish `[a]` and non-list types, which at the very least requires `OverlappingInstances`, but in practice it works acceptably with the even worse `IncoherentInstances`, because we'd also like to resolve polymorphic types depending on the local context.

```
{-# LANGUAGE
  UndecidableInstances, IncoherentInstances, MultiParamTypeClasses,
  FlexibleInstances, TypeFamilies #-}

class MapN a b as bs where
  mapN :: (a -> b) -> as -> bs

instance (as ~ a, bs ~ b) => MapN a b as bs where
  mapN = id

instance (MapN a b as bs, bs' ~ [bs]) => MapN a b [as] bs' where
  mapN f as = map (mapN f) as

-- usage:
> mapN (+1) 0
1
> mapN (+10) [[[0]]]
[[[10]]]

-- note though that without enough context `mapN`'s type is nonsense:
> :t mapN (+0)
mapN (+0) :: Num b => b -> b
```

Comment: Great answer! Lots to digest.

Comment: Your second example seems the most effective for Haskell as I can custom create n-nested maps and map some function onto at n-dimensions into any tensor.

Comment: `IncoherentInstances` should only be available with the `IAmStupid` language extension, and `OverlappingInstances` feels like really weird macro programming.

Comment: `IterN` essentially represents a fixed depth free monad, so we can write [something](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/HomoFree.hs) a bit more general. But plain `IterN` is probably better, since it computes.

Comment: @user3237465 What do you mean your version doesn't compute?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, I added a version (`nmapFree`) that is more similar to **András Kovács**' `mapN`. As you can see it's more complicated and clunky to use, because we now have two datatypes (`[]` and `HomoFree`) and need to coerce between them. That doesn't happen when we use `iterN`: there are only lists. If you only need to map elements, then the free monad is a good choice, but if you also sometimes need to map lists of elements, then `mapN` will save you from numerous and ineffecient coercions.

Comment: @user3237465 It looks fairly complicated. What's the advantage of so much abstraction?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, `HomoFree` is a version of `Free`, which is a well-understood concept, while `IterN` is a fancy type-level function in a language that has awful support for type-level functions. `mapFree` doesn't mention singletons, and you don't need to write things like `sing :: SLit 3`. A good rule of thumb is "use data whenever you don't have strong reasons to use functions". It's easier to perform reasoning about data, rather than functions. But if you just want a generic mapping function, then `mapN` is what you want.

Comment: With regards to `mapN` what changes are required to make it support any functor and not just `[]`?

Comment: After trying your haskell examples, I've met a problem. The specification for how many nested composed maps is currently through type level integer (`sing :: SLit 3`), but I need to compose maps using a value level integer. I tried converting a value level integer into the `SZ | SS n`, but it didn't work. How do you use your `mapN` function with a value level integer?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai: with arbitrary stacks of functors: [here's](http://lpaste.net/141200) one with classes, [here's](http://lpaste.net/141201) one with singletons. Also, you can convert a runtime `Integer` to a singleton [with this](http://lpaste.net/141203). I should probably include it in the library too; there's already an analogous function in GHC.TypeLits (called `someNatVal`), that return GHC's builtin type level naturals (that type is less useful than the unary `Nat` though).

Comment: I used existentials for this kind of stuff too, but then I realized that CPS is nicer. @CMCDragonkai, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27070207/3237465) answer might be helpful.