# Replicating Numpy's Advanced Indexing/Slicing in Haskell

Tags: haskell, numpy, recursion, polymorphism, composition

Numpy has a sophisticated indexing/slicing/stepping functionality in its array access operator. See this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

While experimenting with Haskell, I thought it would educational to try replicating a subset of this indexing functionality. Specifically it's "tuple selection objects" or n-dimensional projection" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_%28relational_algebra%29).

Basically you can do:

```
two_d_array[0:1:1, 0:4:2]
```

And this will give you the first row stepped by 1 containing the first 2 columns stepped by 2 (skipping 1 column).

In order words it can project an original 2 dimensional array into a smaller 2 dimensional array. The result remains as a 2 dimensional array.

So here's what I tried in Haskell.

The type of such a function should be something like:

```
(!!!) :: (Functor f) =>  f a -> [(Int, Int, Int)] -> f a
```

So you could see something like:

```
three_d_tensor !!! [(s1,e1,st1), (s2,e2,st2), (s3,e3,st3)]
```

Where sx, ex, stx are start, end, step respectively.

The example should project the original tensor into a smaller tensor, with the first dimension restricted by `s1 to e1, stepping by st1`, second dimension restricted by `s2 to e2, stepping by st2`... etc.

So here's what I got:

```
slicing from to xs = take (to - from + 1) (drop from xs)

stepping n = map head . takeWhile (not . null) . iterate (drop n)

(!!!) tensor ((start, end, step):tail) = 
    project (stepSlice start end step tensor) tail map
    where 
        project tensor ((start, end, step):tail) projection = 
            project (projection (stepSlice start end step) tensor) tail (projection . map)
        project tensor [] _ = 
            tensor
        stepSlice start end step tensor = 
            ((stepping step) . (slicing start end)) tensor
```

The above does not work due to a problem of "polymorphic recursion". Basically I cannot infinitely compose the `map` function, the specific expression that does this is the `(projection . map)`. If this kind of polymorphic recursion were possible, I believe it would work. But I am open to alternative implementations which doesn't involve polymorphic recursion.

I have researched this problem and have still come up short:

- https://byorgey.wordpress.com/2007/08/16/mapping-over-a-nested-functor/
- http://okmij.org/ftp/Haskell/typecast.html#deepest-functor
- [Haskell Polymorphic Recursion with Composed Maps causes Infinite Type Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536837/haskell-polymorphic-recursion-with-composed-maps-causes-infinite-type-error)

Comment: _Tensors are not functors_ (nested or otherwise). Yes, it sometimes kind of works to pretend so, and [linear](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear) does it, but this is one thing where EKmett got it wrong, IMO. — Do you really need runtime-variable ranks?

Comment: Note that you **can** use polymorphic recursion... provided that 1) the type that the function would have is actually syntactically expressible and 2) you provide an explicit type signature.

Comment: I don't know if either of these relates, but they seem pretty interesting: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#generalised-list-comprehensions and https://hackage.haskell.org/package/DSH

Comment: @Bakuriu do you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536837/haskell-polymorphic-recursion-with-composed-maps-causes-infinite-type-error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's already a type for computing new values from existing values - functions. Assuming we have a function that indexes into a structure, we can use it to index the structure by applying it to the structure.

```
(!!!) = flip ($)

infixr 2 !!!
```

If we have a function that indexes the structure and another function that indexes any nested structures we can compose them together by `fmap`ing the second function over the structure then applying the outer function.

```
(!.) :: Functor f => (f b -> g c) -> (a -> b) -> f a -> g c
t !. f = t . fmap f

infixr 5 !.
```

With an example 3d structure

```
three_d_tensor :: [[[(Int,Int,Int)]]]
three_d_tensor = [[[(x, y, z) | z <- [0..4]] | y <- [0..3]] | x <- [0..2]]
```

We can look up an elaborate slice of it built with your slicing functions `slicing` and `stepping`.

```
example = three_d_tensor !!! slicing 1 2 !. stepping 2 !. stepping 2 . slicing 1 3
```

Which results in

```
[[[(1,0,1),(1,0,3)],[(1,2,1),(1,2,3)]],[[(2,0,1),(2,0,3)],[(2,2,1),(2,2,3)]]]
```

Comment: Wow. This works great actually. You compose all of the dimensional projections together `!.`, then apply it in one go with `!!!`.  I noted the parallel with normal composition `(f b -> f c) -> (f a -> f b) -> f a -> f c` similar to just `(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c`. But instead this kind of "nests" the composition inside the functor's contents. I also noticed that you used `g` to allow a change in the functor itself? What is this kind of transformation called? "Nested composition?"

Comment: The main difference was my original intent was to take a list of projections, which has the advantage of allowing arbitrary projections determined by some runtime value. The current form can only have projections determined at compile time. But runtime metaprogramming or type class hackery or dependent types may allow list based projections.

Comment: You can construct functions at run time; that's what partial application and lambdas do. The only part of this that needs to be done at compile time is type-checking that the projection will be correct.